# Calling functions from the Main Method

Tags: c++, function, methods

I am writing a program for a class I am taking. I am having problems getting the proper output. I have programmed many times before and usually I would make my method declarations global. However our professor told us that we are not allowed to have global functions. All of our functions must be declared in the Main loop. Below is the loop that calls on the two primary functions. The first one runs a calculation. The other one displays the output to the screen. The problem is that the program is not doing the calculation multiple times but instead outputs the same number multiple times. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The loop:

```
 for ( YearNumber = 1; YearNumber <= Years; YearNumber++)   
       {

        /*--------------------------------------------------*/
        /*                                                  */
        /* Call ComputeFutureValue Function                 */
        /*                                                  */  
        /*--------------------------------------------------*/

        ComputeFutureValue (Principle, OnePlusInterestRate, YearNumber);

        /*--------------------------------------------------*/
        /*                                                  */
        /* Call DisplayYearInfo Function                    */
        /*                                                  */
        /*--------------------------------------------------*/

        DisplayYearInfo (YearNumber, FutureValue);  

       }
```

The Compute Function:

```
float ComputeFutureValue (float Principle, float OnePlusInterestRate, int YearNumber)
{
 float FutureValue = Principle * pow (OnePlusInterestRate, YearNumber);

}
```

The display method:

```
 void DisplayYearInfo (int YearNumber, float FutureValue)

{

cout << setw (2)
     << YearNumber
     << setw (22)
     << FutureValue
     << "\n";

}
```

Comment: "However our professor told us that we are not allowed to have global functions. All of our functions must be declared in the Main loop."  That doesn't make sense.  You don't declare functions in `main`.  And how does he define a `global` function?

Comment: I hope you are not planning on commenting every single function called such as you do now? " All of our functions must be declared in the Main loop" I would like to sent this professor an e-mail.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: More mindbogglingly, (where) are you allowed to declare `main()`?

Comment: But as to your problem, you're calling functions that don't return anything and have no way to store their results.  Obviously they will produce the same values each time they're called.

Comment: (And I think you're using the term "functions" when you mean "variables".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `ComputeFutureValue` doesn't return anything - it only declares a local variable that won't be visible outside of the function.

```
for ( YearNumber = 1; YearNumber <= Years; YearNumber++)   
{

  float FutureValue = ComputeFutureValue (Principle, OnePlusInterestRate, YearNumber);


  DisplayYearInfo (YearNumber, FutureValue);  

}


float ComputeFutureValue (float Principle, float OnePlusInterestRate, int YearNumber)
{
  return Principle * pow (OnePlusInterestRate, YearNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all the help. I would like to tell you how I feel about our professor, but there may be kids watching.